# PAX Exam and Configuration Admin

Tags: java, osgi, pax-exam

I'm trying to setup a test for a bundle using PAX Exam.

In the method annotated with `Configuration`, I set up the different bundles that must be loaded before running my test. However, the bundle under test also expects configuration to be provisioned through the Config Admin service.

Outside Eclipse, I use the Apache Felix framework with Config Admin and File Install so that the bundles + configurations are automatically loaded.

How to provision configuration information with PAX Exam?

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple, just let the configuration admin service be injected into your test and do configure it in your setup method. A working sample for this can be found at the pax web project. 
Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/jetty/HttpServiceWithConfigAdminIntegrationTest.java)

Comment: Hello @AchimNierbeck, this example seems good and helped me a lot, but if I want  to inject the service (using DS) which I have developed and that service takes configuration from the file, then how can provide configuration using ConfigurationAdmin in PAX-Exam?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately eclipse don't publish their bundles into a maven repo. What you could do is to search at maven central repo for them or in case you don't find any to install the needed bundles that came with your Eclipse IDE inside you local maven repository and then refer to them inside pax-exam configuration. samething like this:

```
protected static Option[] baseConfiguration(Option... extraOptions) {
    Option[] options = options(
            cleanCaches(),
             when(isEquinox()).useOptions(
                    mavenBundle("org.lunifera.osgi",
                            "org.eclipse.osgi.services",
                            "3.4.0.v20131120-1328").startLevel(1),
                    mavenBundle("org.lunifera.osgi",
                            "org.eclipse.equinox.ds",
                            "1.4.200.v20131126-2331").startLevel(2),
                    mavenBundle("org.lunifera.osgi",
                            "org.eclipse.equinox.cm",
                            "1.1.0.v20131021-1936").startLevel(2), ....

public static boolean isEquinox() {
    return "equinox".equals(System.getProperty("pax.exam.framework"));
}

public static boolean isFelix() {
    return "felix".equals(System.getProperty("pax.exam.framework"));
}
```